# Google Cloud cloud storage operation costs

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am looking into using Google Cloud cloud storage buckets as a cheaper alternative to compute engine snapshots to store backups.

However, I am a bit confused about the costs per operation. Specifically the insert operation. If I understand the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) correctly, it doesn't seem that it matters how large the file is that you want to insert is, it always counts as 1 operation.

So if I upload a single 20 TB file using one insert to a standard storage class bucket, wait 14 days, then retrieve it again, and all this within the same region, I practically only pay for storing it for 14 days?

Doesn't that mean that even the standard storage class bucket is a more cost effective option for storing backups compared to snapshots, as long as you can get your whole thing into a single file?

Answer (score 2):

It's not fully accurate, and all depends on what cost for you.

First of all, the maximum size of an object in Cloud Storage is [5 TiB](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects), so you can't store 1  file of 20Tb, but 4, at the end, it's the same principle.

The persistent disk snapshot is a very powerful feature:

- The snapshot doesn't need CPUs to be done, compared to your solution.
- The snapshot doesn't need network bandwidth to be done, compared to your solution.
- The snapshot can be done anytime, on the fly.
- The snapshot can be restored in the current VM, or you can create a new VM with a snapshot to investigate on it, for example.
- You can perform [incremental snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshots#incremental-snapshots) saving money (cheaper than full image snapshot).
- You don't need additional space on your persistent disk to be done (compared to your solution where you need to create an archive before sending it to Cloud Storage).

In your scenario seems like using snapshots seems like the best solution in terms of time efficiency. Now, is using Cloud Storage a cheaper solution? Probably, as it is [listed](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks) as the most affordable storage option, but in the end, you will have to calculate the cost-benefits on your own.